# How can i pass values from a hidden <asp:content to <input id in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is this possible to pass values in a URL parameter from a Label which is a `<asp:control` to an HTML `<input control`

How is this possible?

I am trying to do this, but I have not seen anything useful so far.

Comment: Pass values how? Client side or server side?

Comment: client side , do i can use the input in the hidden field to show on the textbox

Comment: And the URL part, are both element not on the same page perhaps?